# ant-input-group-addon with non-input elements like ant-select / ant-btn

Tags: antd

How can I use `ant-input-group-addon`with non-input elements like `ant-select` and `ant-btn`? I'm looking for styling HTML/CSS solution, but not React one.

Answer (score 1):

> `ant-input-group-compact` did the trick:

[image]

```
<span class="ant-input-group ant-input-group-compact">

<span class="ant-input-group-addon" style="width:150px;">
<i class="anticon anticon-folder"></i> ant-input-group-addon
</span>

<input type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-sm" value="Button 1" style="width: 20%;">

<input type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-sm active" value="Button 2" style="width: 30%;">

<Select class="ant-select ant-select-selection ant-input-group">
<Option value="Select">Select</Option>
</Select>

</span>
```